# How to Post json data from java to php server?

Tags: java, json, eclipse, post, httpurlconnection

Send json data to server from java code using post request.

I am trying to send id in json by using HTTP-URL-connection from java side.

This is the url
http://xenzet.com/ds/getrec.php?

and this is the format in which it will recieve data.
{"id":null,"date":"22-Dec-18"}

i only need id here to be sent to the server from java side.

if i am recieving id = 5 
then json should be {"id":5,"date":"22-Dec-18"}
this is the java code

```
    try
            {
                 java.net.URL urlForPostRequest = new java.net.URL("http://xenzet.com/ds/getrec.php?");
                 System.out.println("Instantiated new URL: " + urlForPostRequest);
                 Map<String ,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                 params.put("id", resultant);
                 String readLine = null;
                HttpURLConnection conection = (HttpURLConnection) urlForPostRequest.openConnection();
                conection.setDoOutput(true);
                conection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    //                    conection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
                OutputStream os = conection.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");    
                osw.write("Just Some Text");
                osw.flush();
                osw.close();
                os.close();  //don't forget to close the OutputStream
                conection.connect();

               String result1;
              BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(conection.getInputStream());
              ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              int result2 = bis.read();
              while(result2 != -1) {
                  buf.write((byte) result2);
                  result2 = bis.read();
              }
              result1 = buf.toString();
              System.out.println(result1);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

getting file not exception.

Comment: Can you share exeption stacktrace?

Comment: conection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"); solved the exception there is no error but no answer also as  json is really being sent the id.

Comment: Can you give your piece of code of how to send a single variable id to url

Comment: Do you want to send id in URL? Can you please edit your question with the details that you're sharing with me in comments?

Comment: this is from php                                                                                                
    <?php

$id = $_POST['id'];

echo json_encode(array("id"=>$id, "date"=>date("d-M-y")));

?>                                                                                                                                    i want to just post id in response i will get json response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your POST API is accepting *FORM data*, you need to send `id` in form data.

*Consider following,*

```
public class Xenzet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL urlForPostRequest = new URL("http://xenzet.com/ds/getrec.php");
            System.out.println("Instantiated new URL: " + urlForPostRequest);
            final long id = 12;
            HttpURLConnection conection = (HttpURLConnection) urlForPostRequest.openConnection();
            conection.setDoOutput(true);
            conection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
            conection.getOutputStream().write(("id="+id).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            conection.connect();

            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(conection.getInputStream());
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int resultBuffer = bis.read();
            while (resultBuffer != -1) {
                bos.write((byte) resultBuffer);
                resultBuffer = bis.read();
            }
            String result = bos.toString();
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
Instantiated new URL: http://xenzet.com/ds/getrec.php
{"id":"12","date":"22-Dec-18"}
```